# ZipArchive creating a recursive folder structure in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, php-ziparchive

I am creating a zip file in PHP. However, it is creating a recursive folder structure in the output zip files. Any idea what could be the error ?

```
$zip_name = "ZipArchieve.zip" 
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
{
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

foreach($file_array as $file)
{   
    //echo "File : " . $file . '<br/>';
    if (file_exists($file)) 
        $zip->addFile($file);
    else
        echo $file . ' Does not exist'; 
}
$zip->close();

$newPath   = DOC_ROOT.'/downloads/files/' . $zip_name  ; 
rename($zip_name, $newPath);
```

Here is the `var_dump` of the `file_array`.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'C:\xampp\htdocs\downloads/files/4.pdf' (length=37)
  1 => string 'C:\xampp\htdocs\downloads/files/1.pdf' (length=37)
  2 => string 'C:\xampp\htdocs\downloads/files/2.pdf' (length=37)
```

Thanks

Comment: [What about this?](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#110513)

Comment: What do you understand as "recursive folder structure in the output zip files" ? Example please

Comment: @Yunalescar, Yes, I pass the complete path to the files `C:\xampp\htdocs\downloads/files/4.pdf` . Now inside the zip file, I have the new folders created starting from C, xampp, htdocs and so on